# Replacing NAs in one column, with matched data from two others

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm trying to complete the data in one dataframe with data from two other dataframes.
df1 is like this:

```
$ Date: chr [1:9] "2022-10-04" "2022-10-05" "2022-10-06" "2022-10-07" "2022-10-08" "2022-10-09" "2022-10-10" "2022-10-11"
$ Descr Activity: chr [1:9] "Mixed farming" "Support activities for crop production" "Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c." "Post-harvest crop activities" "Processing and preserving of meat" "Processing and preserving of poultry meat" "Production of meat and poultry meat products" "Processing and preserving of fish, crustaceans and molluscs"
```

df2 is like this:

```
$ Descr: chr [1:9] "Mixed farming" "Support activities for crop production" "Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c." "Post-harvest crop activities"
$ SIC: chr [1:9] "01500" "01610" "01629" "01630"
```

df3 is like this:

```
$ Descr: chr [1:9] "Processing and preserving of meat" "Processing and preserving of poultry meat" "Production of meat and poultry meat products" "Processing and preserving of fish, crustaceans and molluscs"
$ SIC: chr [1:9] "10110" "10120" "10130" "10200"
```

I'm trying to get the 'SIC' column info by matching the contents of the 'Descr' columns that exist in all three dataframes. I've been able to achieve it for one, by doing:

```
df$SIC <- df2$SIC[match(df$`Descr Activity`, df2$Descr)]
```

But if I were to simply repeat/adapt the code for df3 data, it simply overwrites the data gathered from df2, and leaves NAs in its place. Is there a way of matching the data (as I've done above) that'll keep the found data from both df2 and df3?
Thanks for any assistance.

EDIT: In answer to one question: unfortunately df2 and df3 is not suitable for this use case.

dput of df1:

```
structure(list(Date = c("2022-10-04", "2022-10-05", "2022-10-06", 
"2022-10-07", "2022-10-08", "2022-10-09", "2022-10-10", "2022-10-11"
), Descr.Activity = c("Mixed farming", "Support activities for crop production", 
"Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c.", 
"Post-harvest crop activities", "Processing and preserving of meat", 
"Processing and preserving of poultry meat", "Production of meat and poultry meat products", 
"Processing and preserving of fish, crustaceans and molluscs"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

dput of df2:

```
structure(list(Descr = c("Mixed farming", "Support activities for crop production", 
"Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c.", 
"Post-harvest crop activities"), SIC = c("01500", "01610", "01629", 
"01630")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

dput of df3:

```
structure(list(Descr = c("Processing and preserving of meat", 
"Processing and preserving of poultry meat", "Production of meat and poultry meat products", 
"Processing and preserving of fish, crustaceans and molluscs"
), SIC = c("10110", "10120", "10130", "10200")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Expected output:

```
$ Date: chr [1:9] "2022-10-04" "2022-10-05" "2022-10-06" "2022-10-07" "2022-10-08" "2022-10-09" "2022-10-10" "2022-10-11"
$ Descr Activity: chr [1:9] "Mixed farming" "Support activities for crop production" "Support activities for animal production (other than farm animal boarding and care) n.e.c." "Post-harvest crop activities" "Processing and preserving of meat" "Processing and preserving of poultry meat" "Production of meat and poultry meat products" "Processing and preserving of fish, crustaceans and molluscs"
$ SIC: chr [1:9] "01500" "01610" "01629" "01630" "10110" "10120" "10130" "10200"
```

Comment: can you share your data with dput

Comment: You probably want to join df2 and df3 with df1 (look at the `dplyr::join_*` functions). Is there a reason that df2 and df3 are separate dataframes. Why don't you just combine them (`rbind(df2, df3)`) if only for the join/match? That would prevent your overwriting problem

Comment: Unfortunately for this use case df2 and df3 can't be combined.

Comment: I've added the dputs, thanks for looking into this

Comment: @alec22 what is your expected output

Comment: Do you want `list(df3, df2, df1 %>% rename(Descr = "Descr.Activity") ) %>%reduce(left_join)`

Comment: Unfortunately joining df2 and df3 is not going to work from a use-case perspective. Is there no way of applying the second match function to rows that are NA after the first?